# Show that the interval $[0,1]$ can be continuously mapped onto the space $Y=\{0,1\}$ whose open sets are $\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0,1\}$.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that the interval $[0,1]$ can be continuously mapped onto the space $Y=\{0,1\}$ whose open sets are $\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0,1\}$.

It seems that the sets $\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0,1\}$ generate the topology on $Y$? If so then if $f : [0,1] \to Y$ I have that $f^{-1}(\emptyset) \subset [0,1]$ is open as well as $f^{-1}(\{0\}) \subset [0,1]$ and $f^{-1}(\{0,1\}) \subset [0,1]$.

Are they asking me to explicitly construct $f$ some how or isn't this enough to show that there exist a continuous map? I assume $f$ could be constructet piecewise somehow?

Comment: Constant map?..

Comment: Constant map cannot map $x \mapsto 0$ & $x \mapsto 1$? Or am I confusing something?

Comment: The constant map works, because your question doesn't say anything about $f$ having to be a surjective map. So you can just define $f : [0,1] \to \{0,1\}$ by $f(x):=0$ for example. You can check that this is indeed a continuous map.

Comment: Probaby you mean **onto** $Y$. If so, edit your question.

Comment: Edited! @PaulFrost

Answer (score 3):

If you want a surjective map, $f$ defined as
$$\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ for } 0 \le x \lt 1/2\\
1 & \text{ for } 1/2 \le x \le 1
\end{cases}$$
is indeed continuous as the inverse images of the 3 given open subsets of $\{0,1\}$ are open in $[0,1]$ (endowed with the usual topology). And $f$ is obviously surjective.

More generally take any open subset $[0,1] \neq U \subseteq [0,1]$ and define

$$f_U(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ for } x \in U\\
1 & \text{ for } x \notin U
\end{cases}$$

$f_U$ satisfies the requirements. And it is easy to prove that you get all possible maps. You need to have $U \neq [0,1]$ in order for $f_U$ to be onto.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if the first case holds. Isn't $f^{-1}( \{0\}) = \{ x \in [0,1] : f(x) \in \{0\} \} = [0, 1/2)$ which is neither closed nor open? Also $f^{-1}( \{0,1\}) = \{ x \in [0,1] : f(x) \in \{0,1\} \} = [0, 1/2) \cup [1/2, 1]$ that is also not open?

Comment: $[0,1/2)$ **is open** for the relative topology of $[0,1]$. The relative topology is the one to look at for a function defined on $[0,1]$.